# Streaming in Beam

Tags: stream, apache-beam

I read Apache beam documentation and understand that it's an unified beam programming model, "batch + stream". But when I am working on Apache beam code, I don't find any stream classes available. How does the stream being taken care using Beam? I am not getting how exactly data streaming usage being used in Beam. is there any architecture diagram which shows it or sample code?

Appreciate your guidance.

Comment: It is not very clear what kind of stream classes you expect in the SDK. Data pipeline in general operates on elements as they come. 

If elements become available to the pipeline in limited batches, e.g. from read-only files, then you can think of it as a batch pipeline.

If elements are continuously coming from a potentially unlimited (unbounded) source, you get what you can think of as a streaming pipeline.

Beam tries to abstract away the differences between batch and streaming pipelines and provide a common model for them.

Comment: That is, you should be able to write a pipeline which you can run against batch or streaming source without changes.

Comment: This is an article which starts from basics: https://www.oreilly.com/ideas/the-world-beyond-batch-streaming-101

You can take a look at other presentations here: https://beam.apache.org/documentation/resources/ , there are some videos which go along with the article above.

Comment: My question is, Documentation says Apache Beam supports Streaming, how does it support data streaming? or Streaming Is handled by Runner and not exactly in Beam code? It should have required classes to stream data right?

Comment: Beam has a bunch of IOs which read (and write) data from somewhere into the pipeline, see https://beam.apache.org/documentation/io/built-in/ . Theoretically you can switch the IO specifics and have the rest of the pipeline unchanged. These IOs determine the way how the pipeline receives the data, whether it's streaming (unbounded) or in batch (bounded). Both unbounded and bounded kind of sources are abstracted by Beam to have the same interface. Specifically the outputs of all IOs are PCollections of elements, and in general case PTransforms are agnostic to how PCollection is produced.

Comment: For example if your pipeline is reading data from a Pubsub topic, you don't know whether it will ever end, data can be published to the topic by someone at any time. This means that Pubsub is an unbounded (streaming) source, and your pipeline will never stop while it's reading from it. If you swap the PubsubIO with a bounded (batch) source, for example BigQueryIO, then you know exactly when your pipeline is going to end (when all data from table is read), but most of the actual data processing logic should stay the unchanged in the pipeline.

Comment: This is good to know. I understand that if the "source" does "streaming" of data to "pipeline", then beam "continue" supporting "streaming" by default. pipeline, PCollection classes helps for this streaming purpose.